# Change global css in react-router based on routes?

Tags: css, reactjs, less

There's a global css class I want to override (.ant-content), but I want to do it per route, I've tried importing css files which override .ant-content per react-component that gets loaded up in various routes but they only end up loading their css even when not rendering (probably because the imports happen regardless if a component is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a class like this somewhere which you want to override:

`.ant-content{
  color: red
}`

you could try using the specifity ordering rules of CSS to override this. So, for example if in one of your routes you have a component you want to overwrite which looks like this

```
<div className='override'>
  <Component className='ant-content/>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you import into that component you could use:

```
.override .ant-content{
  color: blue
}
```

This should override the original `.ant-content` class as it is more 'specific' than the original class declaration.
You can read more about specifity here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp